# Why hbase memstore size and flushed data size are not equal?

Tags: hbase, flush

I was monitoring hbase (0.94.18) data storing and found that memstore size and size of flushed stored data are not the same.

When memstore data size grows up to **128 Mb** it is flushed to HFile. But store file size diff on disk is **36.8 Mb**. Compaction is turned off. It repeats every flush.

**Why does this happen? Have I missed something?**

I was monitoring hbase with some java util using HbaseAdmin + "hadoop fs -du".

Table description:

DATA_BLOCK_ENCODING => 'NONE', ENCODE_ON_DISK => 'true'

Hbase logs:

```
2015-05-14 13:48:06,192 INFO  regionserver.StoreFile (StoreFile.java:close(1334)) - NO General Bloom and NO DeleteFamily was added to HFile (hdfs://localhost:8020/hbase/sometable/8854a960778fe379d454a79e27b653a1/.tmp/dea0e9ac00be44a1a3acba3b900bdf54)
2015-05-14 13:48:06,192 INFO  regionserver.Store (Store.java:internalFlushCache(921)) - Flushed , sequenceid=4460077, memsize=128.0m, into tmp file hdfs://localhost:8020/hbase/sometable/8854a960778fe379d454a79e27b653a1/.tmp/dea0e9ac00be44a1a3acba3b900bdf54
2015-05-14 13:48:06,232 INFO  regionserver.Store (Store.java:commitFile(968)) - Added hdfs://localhost:8020/hbase/sometable/8854a960778fe379d454a79e27b653a1/r/dea0e9ac00be44a1a3acba3b900bdf54, entries=742515, sequenceid=4460077, filesize=36.8m
2015-05-14 13:48:06,233 INFO  regionserver.HRegion (HRegion.java:internalFlushcache(1776)) - Finished memstore flush of ~128.0m/134226872, currentsize=428.4k/438664 for region sometable,,1431608601110.8854a960778fe379d454a79e27b653a1. in 3043ms, sequenceid=4460077, compaction requested=false
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MemStore stores KeyValues (KV) in ConcurrentSkipListMap structure with overhead per KV of 124 bytes on a 64-bit JVM. If your puts have small payload, for example one column with a few bytes of value, you're going to observe a substantial difference between KV heap size and their size on disk. When KVs are persisted on disk, the overhead of ConcurrentSkipListMap, objects and references is obviously not there. The implication is that if you're writing a lot of small puts, your memstore flushes will run faster but will produce smaller HFiles on disk than expected. You might want to adjust HBase compaction settings accordingly, for example by increasing the maximum number of HFiles.